# How do I determine the smallest dimension of an irreducible $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$-module with a prescribed trivial fixed point space?

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, group-rings

This is a [crosspost from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233142/which-group-properties-determine-the-smallest-degree-of-an-irreducible-mathbb) since I haven't found an answer there yet.

I am not very familiar with modular representation theory or Brauer theory yet, however lately I have needed to use $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$-modules for constructing counterexamples.  Right now I am just making them in Magma, but I am looking to understand what I'm doing a little better.

Say that I am given a group $G$ which I would like to act on an elementary abelian $p$-group $E$ so that a prescribed proper subgroup $H\leqslant G$ acts fixed point freely on $E$, with $|H|$ and $p$ coprime.  So, I construct an absolutely irreducible $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$-module with a trivial fixed point space under restriction to $H$.  Often I have other subgroups which I would explicitly like to *not* act fixed point freely on $E$ (usually faithfully or trivially) in which case I also insist the module have a nontrivial fixed point space under restriction to those subgroups.

I am trying to figure out how to determine the smallest dimension of such a module - in other words, I want to know how big $E$ has to be.  Obviously this is going to depend on the structure of $G$, and in particular the structure of $H$.  **Which group properties determine this, precisely?  Does anyone know where I could read about this specifically?**

There is some existing theory.  For example, one can prove that if $F$ is a Frobenius group with cyclic complement $C$, and $F$ acts faithfully on an elementary abelian $p$-group $E$, then $|C|$ divides the minimum dimension of $E$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.  Are there more general results?

Comment: Hmm. No takers?

Comment: Maybe too hard? You could have started with the easier question asking which $H$ act fixed point freely on an elementary abelian $p$-group, or -- if you already know the solution to this question -- given your readers some hints about what you know about $H$.

Comment: I don't know the answer.  I guess it must be too hard.

Comment: Do you know anything nontrivial about finite $p'$-groups $H$ acting fixed point freely on elementary abelian $p$-groups? 

Comment: Well if the entire $p'$-group $H$ acts fixed point freely on an elementary abelian group $E$ then $E\rtimes H$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $E$.  Evidently Frobenius groups with abelian kernels have been classified up to isomorphism in Ch. 13 of this memoir: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.hawaii.edu%2F~ron%2Fpdfpapers%2Fmemoir.pdf&ei=CXKsUJCtOYOe8QTD2IGwDA&usg=AFQjCNG5duYIL2TlLUVuXsC8-T1r-Dp6XA but it is way above my head I am not sure whether one can get the minimum dimension from it.

Comment: Also from what I understand of Brauer theory, representations of $H$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ do not differ from those of $\mathbb{C}$ when $(q,|H|)=1$ (I think?), so perhaps this could be used in some way to find the minimum dimension.  I think there are a couple results in Huppert's character theory book about representations of Frobenius complements, but the bounds aren't very strict.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you mean with "the entire $p'$-group $H$ acts fixed point freely" that each element of $H^#$ acts fixed point freely, whereas in your question you only ask for no nontrivial fixed point for all the group? [For elementwise fixed point free action you surely get strong restrictions on the structure of $H$ - see for example Theorem 8.3.2 in "The Theory of Finite Groups" by Kurzweil/Stellmacher.]

Comment: For representations of $H$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p$ coprime to the order $H$ you get - to my (non-expert) knowledge - only similar behavior as over $\mathbb{C}$ if $\mathbb{F}_p$ contains an $n$-th root for $n$ the exponent of the group $H$ (= least common multiple of the orders of all group elements). See also Geoffrey's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91132/reference-for-restriction-of-a-simple-module-over-a-splitting-field-to-a-smaller

Comment: I just found also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97105/modular-representations-with-unequal-characteristic-reference-request which might be of interest for you.

Comment: Burnside proved that the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$ are cyclic or generalized quaternion. He also incorrectly stated that $H$ must be nilpotent. See John Thompson's 1959 paper on fixed-point free automorphisms of prime order.